# How to activate word-wrap on all unfocused windows in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm programming in vim and I'm having one little problem. My vim is multiple times splitted in both vertical and horizontal directions, and I want to activate word-wrap like `set wrap` when i switch from one window to another with ctrl-w/W, also i want to unwrap like `set nowrap` on focused one. I have no idea how to do this and I was never good at writing scripts for vim. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to archieve, but maybe you could add

```
autocmd WinEnter * set nowrap
autocmd WinLeave * set wrap
```

to your .vimrc. This will trigger a `set nowrap` on a window you enter and a `set wrap` on a window you leave. From the tests I ran, `WinEnter` and `WinLeave` are triggered when you switch between several split windows.

Alternatively, you can replace the `*` by a `*.txt` if you just want these command to be issued only on buffers containing a txt file for instance.

Comment: Vim is simplier than I thought, also amazingly powerful. Thanks for answer.